# After Exception fired it need to send Ajax Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Ajax method and when i catch the controller side exception.I want to pass that exception to Ajax Error method.
In here It doesn't do anything after exception fired.

### Ajax Call

```
function ConNews(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#getnewsdtl").val(),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(newsModelLists),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (news) {
// some code here.
},
 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{

// I want get controller catched exception here.
}

});
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetNews(List<NewsModel> newsModelList)
{
try
{
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newsModelList);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

  return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject("adf"); // I want to send thisone to Ajax error function
}
}
```

Comment: In your catch block, you sending back a valid value so it will never hit the `error` block (that only get hit when there is an exception)

Comment: How to send this value to xhr.Is there any way?

Comment: Nothing in your code makes sense so I have no idea what your really wanting to do, but you could do say `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "your error message");` in the catch block (400 means Bad Request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is basically create a model for response like below

```
public class ResponseResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller bind this model as below

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetNews(List<NewsModel> newsModelList)
{
  ResponseResult result = new ResponseResult();
  try
  {
        result.Data = //Some Data
        result.Success = true;
        result.Message = "Everything Works Fine!!!";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Set Success = false as there is an exception as well as you can pass a message 
    result.Message = "Somethinng Goes Wrong!!!";
    result.Success = false;
    return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
  }
}
```

And in your **Ajax Call**

```
function ConNews(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#getnewsdtl").val(),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(newsModelLists),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
         //check here if result.Success is true or false and than some additional work you can done here
         console.log(result);
        },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
        // You will not get exception here because your Ajax call has been called without any errors if it fails in case of 404 or something wrong in your ajax requeste than you will get exception here
        // I want get controller catched exception here.
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As per mentioned in comment, you're sending valid data in `catch` block. So try  `ajax.complete`, add bool to check whether exception occur or not

```
var checkIfException = false;
function ConNews(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#getFlightPriceIteration").val(),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(ticketModelLists),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        checkIfException = true; //setting true
// some code here.
},
 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{

// I want get controller catched exception here.
},
 complete: function(){
            if(!checkIfException){
                 alert('Exception occur');
            }
        }

});
```